# "test -n && echo not empty" prints "not empty". Is that expected behaviour?

Tags: bash, test

When I execute the following line

```
test -n && echo not empty
```

it prints "not empty". This occurs when you have an empty variable, and test for non-emptyness while forgetting to quote the value:

```
VAR=
test -n  $VAR  && echo wrong 1
test -n "$VAR" && echo wrong 2
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. When only one argument is passed to `test`, a length check is performed. From `man bash`:

> test and [ evaluate conditional expressions using a set of rules based on the number of arguments.
>
> 0 arguments: The expression is false.
>
> 1 argument: The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.

That is, essentially it is the equivalent of `test foo`, but using `-n` as the string.

Answer (score 3):

`test -n` is *prima facie* malformed, since `-n` requires an argument. I believe some historical implementations treated it as a syntax error (and returned a nonzero status). However, in all the shells you're likely to encounter in the 21st century, the behavior is well-defined (by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html), following existing practice): if `test` has only one argument, then it is true if and only if that argument is non-empty.

Note that if you leave out the quotes, the test may end up being false for some non-empty values of `$VAR`. It can even print out an error message if there are globbing characters in `$VAR`.

```
VAR='foo -a -z bar'; test -n $VAR || echo "true... and false is false"
VAR='= n-'; test -n $VAR || echo "this is an equality test"
VAR='*'; test -n $VAR || echo "you may or may not see this depending on what files are in the current directory"
```

`test -z $VAR` is similarly broken.

Ksh, bash and zsh have a `[[ … ]]` conditional construct which imitates the traditional `test` and `[` utilities. Unlike `[`, which either is an external utility or is a built-in that is parsed like one, `[[ … ]]` is part of the shell syntax. There is no word splitting or globbing inside `[[ … ]]`. `[[ -n $VAR ]]` is fine (as long as you don't care that your scripts won't run under other shells such as ash).

Answer (score 1):

Check also `[[ ... ]]`, which does not suffer this behaviour:

```
[[ -n $VAR ]] && echo wrong 3
[[ -n "$VAR" ]] && echo wrong 4
```

Comment: Interesting and worth being aware of, but "suffer" is probably not the right word here... `[[ ... ]]` is not the same as `[ ... ]` which does exhibit the same behaviour as `test` and is the function referred to in `man bash`...     Within `[[ ... ]]` variable do not need to be "$quoted" to be recognized a variable (ie. as an *arg* to `[[` ) ... This boils down to a simple case of: *the variable was not quoted and it should have been.*

Answer (score 0):

Since the bash buildin `test`, and `/usr/bin/test` lead to the same result, I say yes, it is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It seems when you do the following:

```
VAR=
test -n $VAR && echo helloworld
```

It's treating it as though the argument is not there:

```
test -n && echo helloworld
```

And, for some reason, when the argument is not supplied, it always runs the command afterwards (i.e. it displays helloworld). I tried this on another unuary operator and it did the same thing:

```
FILENAME=
test -f $FILENAME && echo helloworld
```

I think if you want to have expected behavior you must quote the argument:

```
VAR=
test -n "$VAR" && echo helloworld
FILE=
test -f "$FILE" && echo helloworld
```

The above yields no message echoing to the screen.

As to is that expected behavior? I can't find it in the documentation anywhere, but, it seems fairly reproducible and consistent.